# stream video into a standalone C++ desktop app

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, video-streaming, desktop-application

I have a native C++ Windows app that needs to display videos from a streaming server. It's a private server, but similar to YouTube -- upload a video, it converts(?) the video, then gives you HTML code to play the video within a web page.

I first tried embedding a Windows Media Player ActiveX control into a MFC app, but when I direct WMP to the URL, it refuses to play the video. WMP won't play YouTube videos either, so I assume both servers 'wrap' the video somehow (?) so it will only play within a browser.

I thought of using the Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX control, but I understand Microsoft has dropped support for it, and it'll be removed from future Windows versions.  My app has the requirement that it be a single-file distribution -- no DLL dependencies other than those that ship with Windows. It's currently generic C++, but I can use MFC or some other framework if needed.

These are my questions:

1. Using the embed URL, can I tell what format the video is in?
2. Is there any way I can use WMP to directly stream videos like this?
3. If I have to embed a web browser, what is the best route to take?
4. In the worst case, if I have to read the raw video via HTTP and display it frame-by-frame, is this possible, or do these streaming servers wrap the video in a way that makes this unfeasible?

Comment: Try ffmpeg or vlc as static libraries to play the stream. Not tried WMP though. Use CreateProcess with pipes to hide player.

Comment: Thanks, @ark1974.  Can VLC be compiled as a static library and linked directly into my app?

Comment: `1` A URL describes, which *name* refers to a resource. It doesn't tell you *what* that resource is. `2` There's nothing useful you can use with Windows Media Player today. `3` WebView 2. It's the only option that can render web content of this decade. `4` Yes, sure. That's what your web browser does after all.

Comment: Thanks, @IInspectable.  Can I create a WebView 2 app as a single-file standalone app, with no runtime or dll download required?  Regarding Question 1, I know the URL itself wouldn't indicate the format; what I meant was, is there an way to determine the video format by navigating to that URL.

Comment: A properly configured web server will send HTTP headers that describe the resource requested (e.g. the actual video format). Many web servers aren't properly configured. As I understand WebView 2's deployment model, you will have to deploy separate binaries alongside your application. I don't think that compiling WebView 2 into a binary is a supported scenario.